# Parse iOS backend - Objects, Arrays, and User data advice

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I hope this isn't an inappropriate post, but I wanted to make sure my first steps implementing parse as my backend are in the right direction to save some time.  I'm new to both iOS programming and the parse sdk, so please bear with me!

In my app, users are able to create various polygon shape overlays on a Google Maps mapView, stored as a GMSMutablePath, which is basically a list of coordinates.  Users will have at least one group of paths, each with at least one path.  There will also be some information stored with each group, stored as strings or numbers.  This information is specific to a single group of paths.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store this data.  My first basic question is 1) Can I store the GMSMutablePath as a whole in the Object data type?  Or does the Object data type refer to a class that is created through parse?  This link (https://www.parse.com/questions/what-is-data-type-of-object-in-data-browser) is the 'best' explanation I found of the Object data type, and it isn't very clear to me.

My gut instinct is no, I can't store the GMSMutablePath object, and that Object refers to a Parse object.  Which leads me to 2) How should I store this data, then?  I can get the individual lat/long values of the coordinates that make up each path, and I can store those as numbers, and use the numbers to recreate the paths elsewhere.  None of the paths should use too many coordinates, and there shouldn't be too many paths in each group.

Playing around a little bit in the data browser, I see that I can store arrays, but I'm not sure how those are formatted, as I'd need an array (of groups) of arrays (of paths) of arrays (of lat/long values).  A little bit of googling tells me it can be done, but doesn't show me how.  Can any datatype be stored in any array, or is a datatype specified?  I'm used to C++ programming, so I'm used to an array containing a single type of element.  What I'm thinking is that I'd need an array of objects, which would be the groups of paths.  Each one of those objects would have the string/number information associated with the group, as well as an array for the paths within the group.  For each one of those paths, it would have to be either an array or an object.  Since for the path I just need the coordinate lat/long values, I think that I can get away with an each path being an array of numbers, and I can write my program to use one array, with odd indexes being lat / even indexes being long values.    That all being said, I'm not sure how to create all of that.  I'm not looking for somebody to write my implementation for me, but all of the examples I can find are much more simple... if anybody could point me in the right direction to do this, or has a better idea of how to do it, I'd love some pointers.

Each user is going to have their own groups, but that data is going to be shared with others at some point.  The data will be associated with the user it belongs to.  With that in mind, my last question is 3) Should I store all of this information specific to a user and their groups on the User class, or make it all a separate class entirely?  My guess it that I should add an Object to the User class, and store the groups within that Object.  I just want to make sure I have that right, with future scalability in mind.  Like, when I pull the group data, am I going to have to pull the entire User data from another user, and if so, is that going to slow things down significantly?  I'm thinking that I do have to send entire user data, but I don't know if that poses any security risks.  Would it be best to have a separate class for the groups, and store the user id associated with the groups? If I do this, should I also store the groups as an object on the User class?

Sorry for the wall of text, but thank you for any guidance you can provide!

If you need any clarification, let me know.

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Your instinct is correct.  Save richer objects by serializing into something network safe, like JSON.

Comment: I saw stuff saying Parse can store pretty much any data that can be saved in JSON format.  By richer objects, do you mean like the GMSMutablePath is a 'richer' object, and needs to be saved as simpler data, or does richer mean more sensitive user data that needs to be secured on the network? And you said 'like JSON', my understanding was that Parse uses JSON formatting, so are you saying Parse is good, or find another JSON alternative? 

Sorry for the stupid questions, I'm still learning the specifics of the terminology.

Comment: How about creating a Parse class called `Path` with fields `owner`, `group`, `coords`, with `owner` being a parse user, `group` either a relation or simply the name of the group, and `coords` the array of coordinates for that path?

Comment: @JakeT. - I'm saying that parse is a fine choice, but like other general-purpose backends, you must create a serial representation of your objects, distinct from how they are in memory of an iOS app ("richer" in that sense, contrasting with "scalar" types like strings and ints etc).  JSON is a perfectly good way to serialize and, yes, used by parse as its import/export format of choice for whole classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a class to hold all the objects turned out to be unnecessary.  It only had a few extra details that were just as convenient to add to the user object, and then have an array of objects on the user.

Some main things to note that I learned are: use addObject to add to an array, rather than setObject to add a single object to a PFObject/User.

Parse fetching/saving happens in background threads, so if you're loading the data to do something specific with it, make sure the code using the data occurs inside a block using the [PFObject fetchInBackgroundWithBlock] method.

Also, as changes are made to the structure of your data on a parse user/object, make sure you sign out of the current user and create a new one on your app, or you may run into lots of undefined behaviour that could crash your app.